# Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3 al verificar huella Digital Persona SDK (SDK Error = -29)

Tags: vb.net, biometrico

Estoy verificando la huella que recibo de una BD SQL Server, el tipo de Dato es varbinary(MAX) pero recibo esta excepción y no tengo idea de que puede ser, os dejo el código de la consulta donde traigo el dato y el método que procesa

> Excepción:
>
> > Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3

```
Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

************** Texto de la excepción **************
DPFP.Error.SDKException: Event Handler has generated an Exception ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFE3
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.MC_verifyFeaturesEx(SafeHandle mcContext, Int32 templateSize, Byte[] templatePt, Int32 featureSetSize, Byte[] featureSet, Int32 reserved0, IntPtr reserved1, IntPtr reserved2, IntPtr reserved3, Double& achievedFar)
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Int32 FARRequested)
   en DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Result& Result)
   en VerifyEnrollerApp.VerifyFinger.Process(Sample Sample) en c:\users\desarrollo 02\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\VerifyEnrollerApp\VerifyEnrollerApp\Form1.vb:línea 322
   en VerifyEnrollerApp.VerifyFinger.OnComplete(Object Capture, String ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample) en c:\users\desarrollo 02\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\VerifyEnrollerApp\VerifyEnrollerApp\Form1.vb:línea 246
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   en DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageEvents.MessageWindow.WndProc(Message& m)


************** Ensamblados cargados **************
mscorlib
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities
    Versión del ensamblado: 11.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 11.0.50727.1
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities/11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.1087.0 built by: NETFXREL4STAGE
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
```

> Consulta de la huella en la BD

```
Private Template As DPFP.Template
Public Function CargarHuella()
        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(Cadena_Conexion)
        Dim a As Byte()
        Dim Result As String = ""
        Dim sql As String
        Try

            conexion.Open()
            sql = "SELECT H_1 FROM HUELLAS WHERE H_Nit_ID = '11' AND H_TypeDocument_ID = '1' AND H_Document_ID = '1032494911'"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conexion)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read Then
            a = reader.GetValue(0)
        End If
            reader.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            conexion.Dispose()

            Dim str As New MemoryStream
            str = New MemoryStream(a) 'Convertirmos los bites en Memory

            Dim template As New DPFP.Template(str) 'Volvemos el Memory en Template para verificar

            CargarTemplate(template)

            Result = "Exito"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Result = "Error: " & ex.ToString
        End Try

        Return Result
    End Function

Protected Sub CargarTemplate(ByVal template As DPFP.Template)
        If Me.TXTMensajes.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New AddTemplateCallBack(AddressOf CargarTemplate)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {template})
        Else
            Me.Template = template
        End If
    End Sub
```

> Proceso de Verificación

```
Private Verificator As DPFP.Verification.Verification    
Protected Sub ProcessSample(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
            DibujarMapa(Sample)

            Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment)

            If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
                ' Comparamos las caracteristicas de la huella tomada con las del template que tenemos
                Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
                Verificator.Verify(caracteristicas, Template, result) '<----ACÁ SE MUERE Y LANZA LA EXCEPCIÓN
                If result.Verified Then
                    SendMensaje("Ok", "Ok", 3)
                Else
                    SendMensaje("KO", "KO", 1)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

¿Qué puede estar fallando, o yo en qué estoy fallando?

Comment: No veo la conexión del error con tu método `CargarHuella()`. Mas bien, como bien indicas, el error sucede con la sentencia `Verificator.Verify(caracteristicas, Template, result)`. ¿Tienes el código fuente de ese método o algún detalle adicional en cuanto a qué es el objeto `Verificator`?

Comment: Si claro, mira  ` Private Verificator As DPFP.Verification.Verification `

Comment: ¿Y qué es `DPFP.Verification.Verification`? ¿Tienes el código fuente? O se trata de una librería externa? ¿Tienes más detalles en cuanto a eso?  Porque por allí anda tu error.

Comment: Es una librería externa del SDK del lector biométrico, yo no la controlo ni nada, es así, es por eso que no sé a que se puede deber esa excepción.

Comment: Tristemente, allí está el problema. Vas a tener que buscar ayuda de los autores de esa librería.

Comment: SI, eso no lo sé, ya que dice que es una Excepción de COMException no controlada... no sé si seria exactamente problema de la libreria o mio, ya que en uno de los ejemplos del SDK funciona correctamente, por eso creo que debe ser del objeto deserializado que traigo de la BD con la huella que genera este error o no sé

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SOLUCIONADO

Ok lo solucioné de la siguiente manera, primero la explicaré.

Al parecer debía instanciar como nuevo objeto las características que se extraen, hice un rastreo con el catch para obtener el código del error que emitia el SDK sobre el proceso fallido, el error es el -29 y en la documentación explican que es cuando hay un error en las características y no se pueden convertir correctamente dejo el código con la corrección, ahí me funciona perfectamente.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Todo el proceso que se encarga de validar la captura de la huella
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Sample"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Protected Sub ProcessSample(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
        Try
            DibujarMapa(Sample)

            Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = New DPFP.FeatureSet '<--- Agregué esta línea y listo, se arregló
            caracteristicas = ExtraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)

            If (Not caracteristicas Is Nothing) Then
                ' Comparamos las caracteristicas de la huella tomada con las del template que tenemos
                Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
                CodesErrors.GetTypeCode()
                Verificator.Verify(caracteristicas, Template, result)
                If result.Verified Then
                    Huella = True
                    UpdateCalidad("Mensaje: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Huella verificada")
                    SendMensaje("Ok", "Ok...", 3)
                Else
                    Huella = False
                    UpdateCalidad("Mensaje: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Huella no coincide")
                    SendMensaje("KO", "KO...", 1)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.HResult = -29 Then '<----Error que me generaba
                SendMensaje("Lo sentimos, ocurrió un error durante la validación de la huella." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "• Message: 'Invalid Feature Set Type'" & vbCrLf & "• Exception Code: " & ex.HResult, "Disculpenos :( - Error Número (" & ex.HResult & ")", 1)
            Else
                SendMensaje("• Exception Message: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "• Exception Code: " & ex.HResult, "Error al Verificar", 1)
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub
```